# Error logs from a WCF application on IIS 7

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, logging

This is my own fault, and I'm just missing something obvious. I am building a WCF REST app, on .Net 4.0, and have it working in development, now. I pushed it up to my production server, and get a 500 error after logging in. Now, I'm sure this is an issue with my application, but here's the rub - I have no idea what the error is - I just get a generic 500 error, even if I do it from the lcoalhost. So, I went looking for a log, but there is no entry in the logs under inetpub, just acouple of 400 and 401 errors from some previous experimenting. What am I missing? Where does my WCF app write log entries to? Or do I have to tell it to write 500 errors to a log somewhere, by hand?  How would I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF apps don't write logs, unless you've adding logging to them.

However the WCF stack can, optionally, write trace files out which you can, sometimes, use to track down the inner exceptions. [MSDN has instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) on how to enable and view them.

However that page doesn't show you how to configure file logging, instead [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) does. You will need to add an XML trace listener which writes to a file,

```
        <listeners>
           <add name="traceListener" 
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
               initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
```

Comment: This soudns like what I'm trying to do - but when I add those xml entities to my web.config, nothing happens - app functions exactly as previous, does not seem to create the log file indicated. Still get a 500 error. Any idea why?

Comment: If there's no WCF log, then maybe the request isn't reaching WCF. When you run it locally, are you running on IIS?

Comment: I just ran it in debug first, which worked, then deployed it to a local copy of IIS, which also worked. It is only when I deploy it to my server that it fails. I built wcf function that does nothing but return a string, and this page works  just fine on my server, so I know I have it configured to talk to IIS, etc. I'm pretty sure the 500 is coming from the function in the WCF application, itself.

Comment: Huh. Got it to work, but had to give it a full path for the log file location. I'm spoiled, used to the ol' 'fail loud, succeed quiet' philosophy of *NIX :D. It's working now, thanks for the pointer!