# WCF MsmqIntegrationBinding - Some XML messages not being picked up

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

I am using a WCF service to pick up messages off of MSMQ.  I have found that some of the messages are not being picked up and I am not sure why.  How can I try to debug this? I don't see any errors being thrown, the service is just not picking up messages off o the queue.  I am using MsmqMessage to enqueue / dequeue the messages.

Message size: 146,000 bytes (not that big).

What I have found: if I cut down the message size (delete some of the content).  So it could be size related or it could be content.  Nothing crazy in the xml though.

Any ideas?

Service Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- use appSetting to configure MSMQ queue name -->
    <add key="QueueName" value=".\private$\MyMessageQueue" />
    <add key="baseAddress" value="http://localhost:8000/test/message" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MessageServiceBehavior" name="WcfServiceClient.MessageServiceClient">
        <!-- .Net endpoint-->
        <endpoint address="msmq.formatname:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\MyMessageQueue"
                  binding="msmqIntegrationBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="DotNetBinding"
                  contract="WcfServiceClient.IMessageProcessor" />
        <endpoint
                  address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MessageServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata />
          <!--<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="20" maxConcurrentSessions="20" />-->
          <serviceTimeouts />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <msmqIntegrationBinding>
        <binding serializationFormat="ActiveX" name="ActiveXBinding" durable="true" exactlyOnce="true">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding serializationFormat="Xml" name="DotNetBinding" durable="true" exactlyOnce="true">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </msmqIntegrationBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:**
When I turn on tracing (Just figured this out) I get this? Doesn't make any sense to me?

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-12-28T20:32:42.8874263Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Execution ProcessName="WcfServiceClient.vshost" ProcessID="6316" ThreadID="12" />
<Channel />
<Computer>MyComputer</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>WcfServiceClient.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
<Source>System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel/58366981</Source>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfAborted()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.EndDequeue(IAsyncResult result, TDisposable&amp; item)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannel.EndTryReceiveRequest(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; context)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ReplyChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Shutdown(Func`1 pendingExceptionGenerator)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.OnClosing()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ListenerHandler.AbortChannels()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ListenerHandler.OnAbort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnAbort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnServiceHostFaulted(Object sender, EventArgs args)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnFaulted()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Fault()
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnChannelDispatcherFaulted(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnFaulted()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Fault()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnListenerFaulted(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnFaulted()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Fault()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Msmq4PoisonHandler.InternalFinalDisposition(MsmqQueue disposeFromQueue, MsmqMessageProperty messageProperty)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Msmq4PoisonHandler.FinalDisposition(MsmqMessageProperty messageProperty)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqDecodeHelper.DecodeIntegrationDatagram(MsmqIntegrationChannelListener listener, MsmqReceiveHelper receiver, MsmqIntegrationInputMessage msmqMessage, MsmqMessageProperty messageProperty)
at System.ServiceModel.MsmqIntegration.MsmqIntegrationInputChannel.DecodeMsmqMessage(MsmqInputMessage msmqMessage, MsmqMessageProperty property)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqInputChannelBase.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, Message&amp; message)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InputChannelBinder.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.TryTransactionalReceive(Transaction tx, RequestContext&amp; request)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.TransactedLoop()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.SyncTransactionalMessagePump()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnStartSyncMessagePump(Object state)
at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.</ExceptionString>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.
```

indicates, that the TransportReplyChannel has already been closed.

Can you provide the source code which shows how you read from the queue? Maybe there is an additional read after the queue object has been closed / disposed?

Comment: Thanks @tobsen.  Figured it out.  I had to set the maxReceivedMessageSize in the Config.  The error I was getting did not lead me to believe that, but it is working now.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Maybe an inner exception which isn't logged by the tracelistener would indicate that the maxReceivedMessageSize was exceeded.

Comment: do you know how I could get to the inner exceptions for WCF?

Comment: This lists links which show how to configure the logging: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5543696/27083 I don't know if it enables logging of inner exceptions.